# Split a slash separated value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a string value like this:

```
\\dsm-smo38\RepositorioEntregable\Archivos\19062016\CAPTACION\BAZ\07566\075660106201515171475.tif
```

I want to get rid of

```
\\dsm-smo38\RepositorioEntregable\Archivos\19062016\CAPTACION\
```

and only keep

```
BAZ\07566\075660106201515171475.tif
```

How can I do that?

Regards!!

Comment: is it a one time thing, will you do it multiple times, or will the part you want to get rid of change? Any specific language?

Comment: Hi, i'm with sql server 2012, i will do it multiple times because the table has many records to show.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aldo, you can try the following. If you are not going to have 'BAZ\' in your string all the time, you can make the code below into a function and pass any string you want to start extracting from. For Example, you can set @FilterStrng ='Archivos'. This would give you the string starting from 'Archivos'.

```
CREATE TABLE #SplashString
    (
      StringText VARCHAR(255)
    );
INSERT  INTO #SplashString
        ( StringText )
VALUES  ( '\\dsm-smo38\RepositorioEntregable\Archivos\19062016\CAPTACION\BAZ\07566\075660106201515171475.tif'  -- StringText - varchar(255)
          ),
        ( '\\dsm-smo38\RepositorioEntregable\Archivos\DOCS1906201601\BAZ\05884\0588402052014‌​2706162.tif'  -- StringText - varchar(255)
          );
DECLARE @FilterStrng VARCHAR(255)= 'BAZ\';
SELECT  STUFF(StringText, 1, CHARINDEX(@FilterStrng, StringText) - 1, '') AS FilteredString
FROM    #SplashString;
```

Comment: That's worked for me, only 1 thing, I quit the create table #SplashString part  and do the following: `DECLARE @FilterStrng VARCHAR(255)= 'BAZ\';
SELECT TOP 100 STUFF(RUTAREPOSITORIO, 1, CHARINDEX(@FilterStrng, RUTAREPOSITORIO) - 1, '') AS FilteredString
from tbl_ope_entregable  where tabla = 'captacion' order by entregable_id desc`. Many many thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

if \dsm-smo38\RepositorioEntregable\Archivos\19062016\CAPTACION\ is consistent you could use replace:

```
select replace(your_column,'\\dsm-smo38\RepositorioEntregable\Archivos\19062016\CAPTACION\','') 
from your_table
```

Comment: Hi Kostia, thanks to answering my question but that value is not consistent, sometimes has \\dsm-smo38\RepositorioEntregable\Archivos\DOCS1906201601\BAZ\05884\05884020520142706162.tif.

Comment: @Aldo Geovani, Do you have BAZ in your string all the time or does it change? Do you want the string starting from BAZ ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming 'BAZ' is always in the column value.

```
SELECT right(your_column, 
len(your_column) - Charindex('BAZ', your_column, 1) + 1) 
FROM
your_table
```

Comment: Thanks Nagaraj. Both answers (Drishya and you) have resolved my problem. Many thanks.